# VBA - Named Range Solution

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I'm going through someone else's code at a new job and I CAN NOT get this line of vba to run. It looks right, but I'm obviously missing something....maybe a setting within VBA or excel that is turned off.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Line erroring out:

```
MRIBFwb.Names.Add Name:="TeamofThree", RefersTo:=.Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(x1Down))
```

Line within surrounding code:

```
'Create Support tab to hold lists for drop-down validation
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Support"
    Set Supportws = Sheets("Support")
    With Supportws
        .Range("A1").Value = "Team of 3"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Leasing Manager"
        .Range("C1").Value = "Market"
        .Range("D1").Value = "SPP/Non-SPP"
        .Range("D2").Value = "SPP & Non"
        .Range("D3").Value = "SPP"
        .Range("D4").Value = "Non-SPP"
        .Range("E1").Value = "Share"
        .Range("E2").Value = "Consol"
        .Range("E3").Value = "At-Share"
        Occ_Summws.Range("C6", "E" & Occ_SummLR).Copy .Range("A2")
        .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
        .Range("B1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
        .Range("C1", .Range("C1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
        .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        .Range("B1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=.Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        .Range("C1", .Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=.Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        .Range("A2").Insert xlShiftDown
        .Range("A2").Value = "All Teams"
        .Range("B2").Insert xlShiftDown
        .Range("B2").Value = "All Lease Mgrs"
        .Range("C2").Insert xlShiftDown
        .Range("C2").Value = "All Mkts"
        .Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True
        MRIBFwb.Names.Add Name:="TeamofThree", RefersTo:=.Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(x1Down))
        MRIBFwb.Names.Add Name:="LeaseMgr", RefersTo:=.Range("B2", .Range("B2").End(x1Down))
        MRIBFwb.Names.Add Name:="Market", RefersTo:=.Range("C2", .Range("C2").End(x1Down))
        MRIBFwb.Names.Add Name:="SameStore", RefersTo:=.Range("D2", .Range("D2").End(x1Down))
        MRIBFwb.Names.Add Name:="Share", RefersTo:=.Range("E2", .Range("E2").End(x1Down))
    End With
```

P.S. MRIBFwb is the workbook name (Set MRIBFwb = ThisWorkbook) at the top of this very lengthy code.

Comment: It has `x1Down` that should be `xldown` as in excel.

Comment: As an aside, if you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module then you'll get a compile error - Variable not defined. It will highlight the `x1Down`.